# How to define a relationship in a rails model where the model has foreign keys that reference static values in another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have user objects that need to reference static values on foreign tables. The users have a fashion choice and a food choice. The fashion choice and food choice tables are simply a list of strings matched with an id. Storing the values in a separate file (CSV, JSON) isn't appropriate for my business case.

I defined a custom method:

```
def fashion_choice
  FashionChoice.find_by(id: self.fashion_choice_id)
end
```

Which works fine, but gives me an N+1 problem because I can't use `includes` in my ActiveRecord queries, due to the association being defined in a custom method.

I am aware that I can use something like belongs_to in the user model to tell rails that the key lies in the Users table, but that feels strange to say that a User belongs to a fashion choice. Is there a better way to do this, or do I just have to do it the idiomatic Rails way?

User table:

`id name fashion_choice_id food_choice_id`

FashionChoice table:

```
id name
1  Halloween
2  Holiday
3  Beach Santa
```

FoodChoice table is similar.

Comment: Please post your both controllers here.

Comment: No controllers, code is strictly in the models.

Comment: Okay Than do it one thing, `def fashion_choice
 self.fashion_choices
end`
And yes no need to add new method on model.Just use map to get associated models record this will not fire another query.

Comment: I don't mean to criticize, but using self.fashion_choices isn't going to work because the relationship isn't defined in the model files, so that's going to throw an error. Also, if I could call self.fashion_choices, I wouldn't need the method in the first place.

Comment: Without relationship How could you get benefits on ROR,Yes you no need any methods for get associated data.